# Merge two Flux streams into a Flux of master detail objects

Tags: spring-webflux

I am attempting to "merge" two `Flux` streams to create a single `Flux` stream.  The resulting objects would be a master detail object.  That is to say the first `Flux` stream provides an id for which the second `Flux` stream will return a list of objects.

I am struggling with the second stream and inserting the resulting list into my object, as I end up blocking the second `Flux`:

```
return someService.getAllThings(language)
        .map(e -> {
            List<Related> related someService.getRelated(e.getId(), language).collectList().block();
            return new IndustryViewDto(e, related);
        })
```

The blocking call is not ideal, and isint allowed anyway.  I dont think the `zip` methods will help here as I need a value from the first `Flux` to create the second `Flux`.

The only other solution I can think of is perhaps I could `flatMap` `e` and the result of the second `Flux` into a tuple, and then `map` that into the final object.

Any points would be most welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can probably do something like:

```
return someService.getAllThings(language)
        .flatMap(e -> {
            return someService.getRelated(e.getId(), language)
                        .collectList()
                        .flatMap(list -> {
                            return Mono.just(new IndustryViewDto(e, list));
                        };
        });
```

I have not checked if it compiles or not, wrote without an editor, but you should get the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, and it is so simple when you look at it.  Once again I was over complicating things. The only compile error I can see is you used `related` rather than `list` in the `Mono.just`

Comment: ah, fixed the typo